# How to bring submit button above Open keyboard in React native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have one screen where we have two `View` components inside one `View`

Now I did styling like the button is at the bottom, when we click on input text, the keyboard opens up and the screen adjusts according to the keyboard view, so we can see input text properly.

But submit button stay at bottom, And I need to brings that up when keyboard is open

[image]

I did like the below, the button is at bottom

The button should be above opened keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'} style={{flex:1}}>
  your code here
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Here a little example https://snack.expo.dev/@davidbmx/example1